# Xpath- how to test for multiple attributes?

Tags: xpath

```
<bookstore>
<book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</title>
    <author>J.K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2007</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
</book>
<book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>1998</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

I need to select the titles of the books that have more than one author. I am unsure of how this can be done. I know there are a few ways I could do this for this particular example but I need to do it in such a way that actually checks for multiple authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/bookstore/book[count(author) > 1]/title
```